# How to make ESLint error when import is any of package, except given imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, import, eslint

I have the following ESLint rule. This disallows MyImport1 and MyImport2 of being imported from `my-package`.

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["warn", {
    "paths": [
    {
        "name": "my-package",
        "importNames": ["MyImport1", "MyImport2"],
        "message": "Only MyImport1 and MyImport2 are allowed to use from this package."
    }
    ],
}],
```

Now I would like to achieve the exact opposite. If I import any other import than these from this package, I would like to throw an error.

```
import { MyImport89 } from 'my-package'; // Show error: This is not MyImport1 or MyImport2
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to achieve, so that I don't have to manually declare all the imports to block. We basically want an `allowList` instead of a `blockList` for `importNames`. I haven't found any way to do this directly, but I think I'm going to just block all imports from the package and then re-export the ones I want to allow with an `eslint-disable` for the file.

Comment: @blwinters Have a look at the PR for this feature: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/16196